# Website is not available on Chrome after moving to Netlify DNS

Tags: google-chrome, dns, godaddy

I've moved a web site from a private hosting company to Netlify.

Since I also had the domain name from Godaddy, I've used Netlify DNS (dns1.p02.nsone.net) in Godaddy for that domain (birth2day.com).

To my surprise, Chrome still cannot access that site, although Firefox and Safari can. It has been 3 days since the DNS change. Still not accessible with Chrome.

Any ideas why this happens only on Chrome?

EDIT:
I have got `mail.birth2day.com` subdomain for mails.
Now `mail.birth2day.com` is accessible from Chrome but `birth2day.com` is still not accessible from Chrome. What is happening here!

Comment: Have you cleared the cache, etc?

Comment: Yeah cleared the cache, restarted, flushed DNS.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to do a clean install - when I've used Chrome I've found it contains phantom data - a full uninstall should hopefully fix it